# Moving database calls to a separate thread, without busy wait

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my app, I need to access a database (I use SQLite). Sometimes DB calls can take some time(even though the DB is local) so I want to avoid blocking the main thread. I want to move my database class. A class that holds the DB connection and actively accesses the database to a separate thread.

So far my approach has been scheduling my DB call on the `ThreadPool` with the help of `QueueUserWorkItem` and feeding it a delegate callback to the main thread like so:

**DB Class:**

```cs
public void LoadActorBatchThreading(OnGotActorsFromDBDelegate onGotActorsFromDbDelegate,
                                    string                    searchString = "")
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
    {
        var ans = new List<ActorModel>();
        using (var conn = new SqliteConnection(DB_PATH))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText =
                        "SELECT * FROM actor where Actor.name like @Search";


                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter
                {
                        ParameterName = "Search",
                        Value         = $"%{searchString}%"
                });

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var actorModel = new PopulateScrollView.ActorModel
                    {
                            Id        = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            Name      = reader.GetString(1),
                            ThumbPath = reader.GetString(4),
                            Gender    = reader.GetInt32(2)
                    };
                    ans.Add(actorModel);
                }
            }
        }
        onGotActorsFromDbDelegate?.Invoke(ans);
    });
```

It works, but the problem with this is that many DB calls can be sent in parallel. For example, a DB write call can be made while another thread is already writing to the DB. Which would result in an exception.

I want to make something like a job queue on my database class where other classes queue jobs with delegate callbacks and the database class **executes those jobs sequentially.**

Usually, this is achieved by extending the `Thread` class and implementing the `run()` method. Usually with a busy-wait loop.

So first of all, I'm not even sure how to implement this by extending the `Thread` class, because of all the guides on threading in C# I saw show that `Thread` must take a delegate to run. And as far as I know, extending `Thread` is not even an option. But even if it was, I would like to avoid a Busy-Wait loop.

In my mind, this should work like this:

1. Main thread schedules DB job in the DB class job queue.
2. Job scheduling wakes up the DB thread.
3. Db thread executes jobs until the job queue is empty and goes to sleep until the next job scheduling.
4. (While DB thread is executing jobs, the main thread can add more jobs to the queue.)

Though I'm not sure how to achieve this in C#. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This isn't really relevant to the question but this is the calling code I use in the main thread.

**Main Calling Thread:**

```cs
//delegate declaration
public delegate void OnGotActorsFromDBDelegate(List<ActorModel> actors);

// Calling function
private void LoadBatch(string searchString = "")
{
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    OnGotActorsFromDBDelegate onGotActorsFromDbDelegate =
            new OnGotActorsFromDBDelegate(actors => syncContext.Post(_ => OnGotActorsFromDb(actors), null));

    DbManager.Instance.LoadActorBatchThreading(onGotActorsFromDbDelegate, searchString);
}


// Db Callback
private void OnGotActorsFromDb(List<ActorModel> actors)
{
    foreach (var i in actors)
    {
        var scrollViewItemInstance =
                GameObject.Instantiate(scrollViewActorThumb, scrollViewContent.transform, true) as GameObject;


        scrollViewItemInstance.GetComponent<ActorThumb>().ActorModel = i;
        scrollViewItemInstance.gameObject.name                       = i.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: sqlite is an **in-process** file-based database, and as such does not support true parallel access. If you really want parallelism, you'll want a server-class database like MySql, Postgresql, Sql Server, or Oracle.

Comment: Can you use async/await functionality?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't want parallelism in the database. I know SQLite doesn't support parallelism. I want the DB calls to not block my main thread, but I do want all DB calls to process sequentially. Please read the question until the end.

Comment: @Fermin I'm not sure. Isn't async/await execute on the same thread? I'd like to keep the load on my main thread to a minimum. Or maybe I just don't understand what you are saying. How would you propose to use Async/Await in this scenario?

Comment: No need to make this convoluted, use `lock` to ensure only one thread can do anything with sqlite.

Comment: Have you checked the [`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.exclusivescheduler)? You may use it to schedule tasks that can only run one after the other.

Comment: @HansPassant Kinda awkward I didn't think of this by myself. I've put a 'lock' inside the `ThreadPool` and it seems to work just fine. Thank you!

Comment: If you prefer the awaiting to be asynchronous, instead of `lock` you could use [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What do you mean? I don't have an `await` inside the lock block... Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean removing all this `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` machinery, and replacing it with awaitings on `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`. The UI will not be blocked, and the access to the database will be exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You could offload the data access invocations to the `ThreadPool` by using the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method, and enforce a no-concurrency policy by using a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) with capacity `1`. To avoid repeating the same boilerplate code on every DB call, you could wrap it inside a generic method like the one below:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _dbSemaphore = new(1, 1);

public Task<TResult> DBCall<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await _dbSemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        try { return function(); }
        finally { _dbSemaphore.Release(); }
    });
}
```

Then you could safely call the database, without blocking the main thread:

```
int result = await DBCall(() => (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Another idea is to go one step further, and limit all database access to a single dedicated thread. I am not sure if this offers any tangible advantages, but seems a bit tidier and possibly safer as well. To achieve this you could consider implementing a custom [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) that queues tasks to a long-running thread:

```
public class SingleThreadTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Task> _queue;
    private readonly Thread _thread;

    public SingleThreadTaskScheduler()
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
        _thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (var task in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                TryExecuteTask(task);
        })
        { IsBackground = true };
        _thread.Start();
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task) => _queue.Add(task);

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task,
        bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) =>
            Thread.CurrentThread == _thread && TryExecuteTask(task);

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => 1;
    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks() => _queue;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
        _thread.Join();
        _queue.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The `DBCall` method can then make use of the custom `TaskScheduler` like this:

```
private readonly SingleThreadTaskScheduler _stts = new();
private readonly TaskFactory _singleThreadTaskFactory = new(_stts);

public Task<TResult> DBCall<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
{
    return _singleThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(function);
}
```

No locking mechanism is required. The exclusiveness is guaranteed by the task scheduler.

A good idea is to `Dispose` the `SingleThreadTaskScheduler` instance before closing the program, in order to ensure that all pending data access operations have completed before exiting. Otherwise the background thread might be aborted in the midst of executing some fired-and-forgotten DB command.

Comment: Great answer. However this will not work with Entity Framework. You will receive a `System.ObjectDisposedException` due to the database context being passed around and possibly terminated before the new thread has a chance to write to the DB.

Comment: @heyyy yes, you must be careful with the [lifetime management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) of a `DbContext`. The simplest way to handle it is to create a separate `DbContext` for each operation, and dispose it after the operation is complete (the `using` statement is handy for this).

Comment: if you have an example I would appreciate it. 
I cannot inject my `dbcontext` into the `SingleThreadTaskScheduler` class.
I injected my `dbcontext` into another class and put that class method into the `DBcall` function, but still received the System.ObjectDisposedException. 
I don't think it will work, but try it and let me know. Sometimes I get lucky and it writes before the context is disposed of, but it's not reliable. Thanks

Comment: @heyyy aha, dependency injection. Unfortunately I haven't studied these concepts, so I can't help you solve this problem. You could consider posting a new question about this, so that you can get advice from the dependency injection experts on this site. :-)

Comment: OK last comment on this. I ended up making a new `DBContext` every time like you suggested using a `DbContextFactory`. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) It saves ~200-500ms on the API call return time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please user async and await its perfect for what you want. or if you dont have experience with that use [Tasks] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-task) as described below.

```
var task2 = Task < List < ActorModel >> .Factory.StartNew(() => {
var ans = new List < ActorModel > ();
using(var conn = new SqliteConnection(DB_PATH)) {
conn.Open();
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText =
"SELECT * FROM actor where Actor.name like @Search";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter{
ParameterName = "Search",
Value = $ "%{searchString}%"
});

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) {
var actorModel = new PopulateScrollView.ActorModel{
Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
Name = reader.GetString(1),
ThumbPath = reader.GetString(4),
Gender = reader.GetInt32(2)
};
ans.Add(actorModel);
}
}
}
onGotActorsFromDbDelegate ? .Invoke(ans);

return ans;
});
```

Comment: "please user async and await its perfect for what you want". Could you please explain how? 

Regarding the task solution you provided. Wouldn't I still have a problem if two tasks are started on different threads and are trying to access the DB connection together? In this scenario, the DB would be locked and the second task will get an exception.

Comment: a select statement will produce a shared lock in the Sql server. so more then one query can be run at the same time.